# Is correct to have an aggregate with fields different than database object?

Tags: java, oop, domain-driven-design, modeling, aggregates

I'm trying to apply DDD and I have some doubts. I'm reading Scott Millet DDD book and I've just read Aggregates chapters.

Imagine a simple domain model like this:

```
class Candidate
val id: CandidateId
val name:Name
val musicStylesPreferences: List<MusicStyle>
val sportPreferences: List<Sport>
val smoking: Boolean
```

```
enum MusicStylePreference
ROCK, METAL, POP, HIPHOP
```

The other objects are like this.

If we think about persisting the `Candidate`, my approach is like this:

```
*DatabaseObject*
CandidateVO
val id: String
val name: String


MusicStylePreferenceVO
val candidateId: String
val StyleName: String
```

When I persist the `Candidate` object in database I will persist in the appropriate table and when I hydrate the aggregate, I will query the tables.

I'm not sure if this approach is correct, I'm also thinking that maybe the objects like `MusicStylePreference`, `Smoking` etc ... doesn't need to be consistent and transactional (some of the advantages of aggregates) and can be outside of the aggregate `Candidate`.

What do you think?

I appreciate any answer. Thanks :)

Answer (score 4):

It's correct and even necessary. The Aggregate should model the ubiquitous language while the database field names are about persistence and have other separate goals and requirements.

A contrived example; The database might save a fullname as "Firstname", "LastName" but the aggregate just has a string.FullName that's a concatenation of the values. It doesn't care how they are persisted or even where.

Comment: I totally agree except for the given example. If the aggregate has only fullname property it cannot be persisted in 2 different fields in the database since there is no way to get first name and last name from the aggregate.

Comment: There is. You split fullname when you serialize. The point of this contrived example is to show that some domains will transform serialized data to match their ubiquitous language.

Comment: Thank you very much @Louis and Mohamed, I have some doubts but you confirmed that I was right. I will read again the chapter to ensure the knowledge. Regards!